# Change style of titles for Remark and Definition environments

Tags: fonts, environments

I want to change the titles (not the body) for Remark and Definition (not for Assumption) to itshape and not bold. Could you help me to do it? Here a working example

```
\documentclass[11 pt,a4paper, oneside, openany, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[inner=15mm,outer=15mm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\newcommand{\thmsymbol}{\( \diamond \)}

 \newtheorem{remarkex}{Remark}
\newenvironment{remark}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\remarkex}
  {\popQED\endremarkex}

 \newtheorem{definitionex}{Definition}
\newenvironment{definition}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\star$}\definitionex}
  {\popQED\enddefinitionex}

\newtheorem{assumptionex}{Assumption}
\newenvironment{assumption}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\bullet$}\assumptionex}
  {\popQED\endassumptionex}



\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{\normalfont (blah1)}
{\normalfont
blah2}
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}{\normalfont (blah1)}
{\normalfont
blah2}
\end{remark}

\begin{assumption}{\normalfont (blah1)}
{\normalfont
blah2}
\end{assumption}




\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very easy to do with `ntheorem`, which furthermore has an automatic placement of end-of-theorem symbols (and cooperates with `thmtools`).

Comment: Could you help me with an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you delve into the `amsthm` documentation.

Here is a basic example with `amsthm`

```
\documentclass[11 pt,a4paper, oneside, openany, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[inner=15mm,outer=15mm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\newcommand{\thmsymbol}{\( \diamond \)}

\newtheorem{assumptionex}{Assumption}
\newenvironment{assumption}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\bullet$}\assumptionex}
  {\popQED\endassumptionex}

\newtheoremstyle{mythm}%
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{}% Body font 
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head ⟩
{.5em}% Space after theorem head 
{}%

\theoremstyle{mythm}
 \newtheorem{remarkex}{Remark}
\newenvironment{remark}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\remarkex}
  {\popQED\endremarkex}

 \newtheorem{definitionex}{Definition}
\newenvironment{definition}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\star$}\definitionex}
  {\popQED\enddefinitionex}





\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[blah1]
{blah2}
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}[blah1]
{blah2}
\end{remark}

\begin{assumption}{ (blah1)}
{blah2}
\end{assumption}




\end{document}
```

with this result:

[image]

What I did is defining a new theoremstyle with `\bfseries` as theorem head font. Please also note that `normalfont` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done with `ntheorem`. Note it is quite easy to change the end-of-theorem symbol, and that its placement is automatic, even when the theorem ends up in a displayed equation.

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper, oneside, openany, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts ,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[inner=15mm,outer=15mm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\triangle}}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\star}}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\bullet}}
\theoremseparator{\upshape:}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  blah2
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}
  blah2
\end{remark}

\begin{assumption}
  For all $ x, y, z ∈ \mathbf R$, one has
  \[ (x + y) + z= x +( y + z) \]
\end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

[image]